# image in the website i'm working on is not showing

Tags: html

so i was working on my website and was trying to put images into the website dashboard but the image isn't loading here an image for proof and my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>super funnis meme submit</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <img src="super funnis logo.png" alt="super funnis" width="100" height="50">
        <h1>welcome here submit your memes</h1>
        <p>your memes will later be tweeted by the twitter bot</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

i tried to do it again hoping the image shows up but it didn't

Comment: what error code does the dev tools console output? 404? 403?

Comment: The problem is almost certainly the image src. Make sure it is in the same directory as your html file and the name is correct.

Comment: @Henry the png file is called super funnis logo.png vs code put an underline under it

Comment: Is it in the same directory as your HTML file?

Comment: @Henry i don't what your really talking don't blame i'm a beginner and what do mean by same directory can you show me an example of what needs to be done?

Comment: A directory is a folder. Are the files both in the same folder?

Comment: @Henry not it isn't

Comment: If you don't want to move it to the same folder, assuming you are using Windows, go to the image in the file explorer, click it once, then hold shift and right-click the image and click "Copy path as", then paste that as the img src.

Answer (score 0):

At the src attribute:

1. Be sure you have the correct file name and file path.
2. Make sure the image file is placed in the same folder or directory as your html file,
   to enable its file path to be relative to the current html page.  For example,
   your html file path is "super-funis/index.html" and your image file path is "super-funis/logo.png".
   According to the example above, both the html file path and image file path points to "super-funis" folder.